# get an index from a scrollview

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im try to delate item from a scrollView when the user have a long press on it.

so , if the item of the scroll view coming from a simple array(named post), I manage to the get the isse done using firstIndex(of: item)! and

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            HStack(spacing: 100) {
                ForEach(post, id: \.self){ item in

                    ZStack {

                        Text(item).onTapGesture {

                            self.post.remove(at: self.post.firstIndex(of: item)!)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            }
        })
```

my isse now is, if my array (named storage) is of type model:

```
class DataModel:Identifiable , Codable {
    var nameAirport : String
    var countryAirport : String
    var icaoAirport : String
    var metar: String
    var taf : String
```

how can I find the index to pass at the method remove?
.firstIndex(at: ) not exist I found only .firstIndex(where:) but I can't find how to use it?
any idea how to find this index?

here below my code? thanks for helping me...

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(dm.storage) { item in

                            VStack {

                       Text(item.icaoAirport).onLongPressGesture {

                                    self.dm.storage.remove(at: ) //// how can i get index 
                                    ///
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it without using any argument like this:

```swift
Text(item.icaoAirport).onLongPressGesture {
    self.dm.storage.remove
}
```

Normally, it should work. I used this technique with `.onDelete(self.dm.storage.remove)`.
If it doesn't work I suggest you add an ID to your model.